# Is it possible to develop an extension that manipulates Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to create a [FireSass](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/) plugin for Chrome I couldn't find any API that can manipulate the Chrome Dev Tools. I wonder if it is possible to manipulate it?

Comment: Is there any progress with the development? It would be a really awesome extension, especially if it can be combined with Autosave.

Comment: @parrket9: There is some design issues left. But the hard part of creating this extension is done. The thing is nobody will use this extension because it is now at the bottom in side bar pane. I'm contributing to developing  chrome right now to fix this problem. What do you mean by Autosave?

Comment: I meant this Chrome extension: https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave It basically allows you to save the changes you do to CSS and JS files automatically. If you change a CSS property value, it is saved to the file straight away. It would be an awesome thing to do, but even without it, it will still be enormously helpful! Thanks for you efforts, and I hope we will all see and use this tool in a while.

Comment: @parrker9 it is done now. Please give med some feedback! https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lkofmbmllpgfbnonmnenkiakimpgoamn?hl=sv&gl=DE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`chrome.devtools.*`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/devtools.html) API methods can be used to change the panels in the Developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [new alternative to FireSass](http://bricss.net/post/33788072565/using-sass-source-maps-in-webkit-inspector) in Chrome. Even though it is listed as an experimental feature, works well for me.